# OpenCV Python bindings for cv::ml::SVM::trainAuto

Tags: opencv, svm, python-bindings

I want to estimate the optimal C and gamma parameters for my SVM training in OpenCV. If I understand the [master (3.1-dev) docs](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d2d/classcv_1_1ml_1_1SVM.html#a7691fe53ff9b30f77afac2c50c29609d) correctly `cv::ml::SVM::trainAuto` would be fit perfect for my needs (using cross-validation to estimate the perfect parameters).

But I can't find the Python Bindings for trainAuto.. I tried to find it using:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.1.0-dev'
>>> help(cv2.ml)
```

or in the ml_SVM object

```
>>> help(cv2.ml.SVM_create())
```

But I only found

```
SVM_create(...)
    SVM_create() -> retval

SVM_load(...)
    SVM_load(filepath) -> retval
```

in the cv2.ml module and

```
train(...)
 |      train(trainData[, flags]) -> retval  or  train(samples, layout, responses) -> retval
```

in the ml_SVM object. Is there another "python way" for trainAuto or are the bindings moved/missing? I'm using python 3.4 on Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score -1):

It is a current open issue with OpenCV for Python: see here https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/7224.

Comment: I know.. I opened the issue ... as you could see in the reference to SO ... "[...] Yesterday I wrote ---->this question<---- on stackoverflow [...]."

Comment: Ah ok saw this a while ago and didn't make the link sorry